# Google Analytics Site Search with Google Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I currently have deployed Google Tag Manager on my site and only have a single, standard Google Analytics tag in my container that fires on every page.  I would like to capture the terms visitors to my site use when searching for products on our site.  Back in Google Analytics, I have enabled Site Search and provided the query parameter in my URLs containing visitors' site search terms.  However, no data ever makes it back to the site search reports in Google Analytics, so I am wondering if I need to create a separate tag in Tag Manager to handle this.

Can someone please advise on how to use Google Analytics Site Search with Google Tag Manager?  I'm very new to both Google Analytics and Tag Manager, so any guidance and details would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this.  It turns out that I just needed to create a version of my container in Tag Manager and publish it after modifying the query parameters in my Google Analytics profile settings. Site search data is now flowing into Google Analytics.